# Using recursion on list of lists

Tags: haskell, sudoku

I have a matrix which is a list with nine lists inside it. A visual representation of my matrix is of a sudoku.

[image: Image of Sudoku]

I need to return the numbers (or elements) in each box (3x3) of the sudoku.
For example, the first three rows from this picture would be represented as

```
rows = 
[[Just 8, Nothing, Nothing, Just 4, Nothing, Just 6, Nothing, Nothing, Just 7],
[Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Just 4, Nothing, Nothing],
[Nothing, Just 1, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Just 6, Just 5, Nothing]]
```

and what I want my function to return for the first box (and later on for the whole sudoku) is

```
[[Just 8, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Just 1, Nothing], ...]
```

Here is my attempt: I created a function which takes the first three elements from the first three lists and returns them.

```
getEm :: [[a]] -> [a]
getEm x = concatMap (take 3)(take 3 x)
```

I then created another function which would remove the first three elements from the first three lists

```
dropEm :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
dropEm x = delete itemZ listTwo
    where
    listOne = delete itemX x
    listTwo = delete itemY listOne
    itemX = (x!!0)
    itemY = (x!!3)
    itemZ = (x!!6)`
```

Here is the part I am stuck with. My goal is to create a recursive function which takes a matrix and then uses `getEm` to take the first three elements of the first three lists (a box) and adds them to a new list `finalList`. Then the function `dropEm` removes the first box (first three elements of the first three lists) and then the whole process repeats until the list is empty and there are no "boxes" to deal with. When the process is complete, the function just returns `finalList`.

Here is what I have come up with, but I do not understand how to implement the recursive part with the two functions I created.

```
boxs m = case startList of
   [] -> finalList

   where
   startList = (chunksOf 3 (concat m))
   finalList = []
```

Comment: Try this for the first  square: `concatMap (take 3) (take 3 rows)`.

Comment: @n.m. That works, but thats just the first square. How do I recursively obtain the rest of the squares so that they are all in one list.

Comment: Are you really sure you want to do that? If you want to ultimately obtain a list of boxes, there are simpler ways. In order to get to an arbitrary box, you may want to use the `drop` function.

Comment: Yes, ultimately I need a list which has lists of all the elements that are inside each box.

Comment: How about: `concatMap (chunksOf 3) . transpose . map (chunksOf 3)` ? :-)

Comment: @basile-henry It returns an error
`No instance for (Show ([e0] -> [[e0]]))
      (maybe you haven't applied enough arguments to a function?)
      arising from a use of ‘print’
    In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it`

Comment: Yeah, you're supposed to apply it to rows: `f = concatMap (chunksOf 3) . transpose . map (chunksOf 3)` and then `f rows`

Comment: Sorry my bad, it works! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just going to put the answer here, since the comments section is probably not the right place for people to see it.

```
import           Data.List       (transpose)
import           Data.List.Split (chunksOf)

subSquares :: Int -> [[a]] -> [[[a]]]
subSquares size = concatMap (chunksOf size)
                . transpose
                . map (chunksOf size)
```

For example:

```
λ > rows = [[(x, y) | x <- [0..8]] | y <- [0..8]]
λ > subSquares 3 rows
[[[(0,0),(1,0),(2,0)],[(0,1),(1,1),(2,1)],[(0,2),(1,2),(2,2)]],[[(0,3),(1,3),(2,3)],[(0,4),(1,4),(2,4)],[(0,5),(1,5),(2,5)]],[[(0,6),(1,6),(2,6)],[(0,7),(1,7),(2,7)],[(0,8),(1,8),(2,8)]],[[(3,0),(4,0),(5,0)],[(3,1),(4,1),(5,1)],[(3,2),(4,2),(5,2)]],[[(3,3),(4,3),(5,3)],[(3,4),(4,4),(5,4)],[(3,5),(4,5),(5,5)]],[[(3,6),(4,6),(5,6)],[(3,7),(4,7),(5,7)],[(3,8),(4,8),(5,8)]],[[(6,0),(7,0),(8,0)],[(6,1),(7,1),(8,1)],[(6,2),(7,2),(8,2)]],[[(6,3),(7,3),(8,3)],[(6,4),(7,4),(8,4)],[(6,5),(7,5),(8,5)]],[[(6,6),(7,6),(8,6)],[(6,7),(7,7),(8,7)],[(6,8),(7,8),(8,8)]]]
```

Which, reformated, gives:

```
[ [ [(0,0),(1,0),(2,0)]
  , [(0,1),(1,1),(2,1)]
  , [(0,2),(1,2),(2,2)]
  ]
, [ [(0,3),(1,3),(2,3)]
  , [(0,4),(1,4),(2,4)]
  , [(0,5),(1,5),(2,5)]
  ]
, [ [(0,6),(1,6),(2,6)]
  , [(0,7),(1,7),(2,7)]
  , [(0,8),(1,8),(2,8)]
  ]
, [ [(3,0),(4,0),(5,0)]
  , [(3,1),(4,1),(5,1)]
  , [(3,2),(4,2),(5,2)]
  ]
, [ [(3,3),(4,3),(5,3)]
  , [(3,4),(4,4),(5,4)]
  , [(3,5),(4,5),(5,5)]
  ]
, [ [(3,6),(4,6),(5,6)]
  , [(3,7),(4,7),(5,7)]
  , [(3,8),(4,8),(5,8)]
  ]
, [ [(6,0),(7,0),(8,0)]
  , [(6,1),(7,1),(8,1)]
  , [(6,2),(7,2),(8,2)]
  ]
, [ [(6,3),(7,3),(8,3)]
  , [(6,4),(7,4),(8,4)]
  , [(6,5),(7,5),(8,5)]
  ]
, [ [(6,6),(7,6),(8,6)]
  , [(6,7),(7,7),(8,7)]
  , [(6,8),(7,8),(8,8)]
  ]
]
```

Thanks to [n.m.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44043892/using-recursion-on-list-of-lists?noredirect=1#comment75114779_44043892) for the initial idea. :-)